# Compile gradle project dependency into android library arr

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm using android studio with gradle to build android library.

I'm adding a project dependency to the library, but I want the build task to include all the project classes in the arr output.

Currently, all the project classes are not included in the arr (just like with other external dependencies)

This is the gradle file i'm using:

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.12'
    compile project(':audit')
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the transitive flag to include the dependencies.

```
compile ('com.somepackage:LIBRARY_NAME:1.0.0@aar'){
    transitive=true
}
```

Comment: I tried that, it's a project dependency, so I used:

compile (project(":audit")){
        transitive=true
    }

Didn't work